# Declare a variable inside of a projection

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Note below that I need to declare a variable which is the result another query. If don't do this, I need to repeat this query anytime where I need the value.

SQL Server is throwing an exception about not to write `DECLARE` inside of the `SELECT` keyword. What can I do or what I'm missing?

```
SELECT A.StudentId,
(
        CASE WHEN (SELECT B.OverwrittenScore
            FROM dbo.OverwrittenScores AS B
            WHERE B.StudentId = A.StudentId AND B.AssignmentId = @assignmentId) IS NOT NULL
            THEN (SELECT B.OverwrittenScore
                FROM dbo.OverwrittenScores AS B
                WHERE B.StudentId = A.StudentId AND B.AssignmentId = @assignmentId)
            ELSE (-- ANOTHER QUERY, BY THE MOMENT: SELECT 0
            ) END
) AS FinalScore
FROM dbo.Students AS A
```

Inside of the parenthesis I need to implement some logic, I mean maybe implement another two queries.
I was thinking if here I can use the BEGIN keyword, but it didn't worked out

Comment: Maybe, *just maybe*, if you shared with us what kind of logic you want to implement inside your subquery, you might *possibly* get some better help! On the (preposterous, I know) theory that we are not mind-readers and need information on the task you're trying to accomplish in order to make useful suggestions.

Comment: Added more information, read the comment on your post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need all that craziness. There are a lot of conceptual problems with what you're trying to do.

1. You can't declare variables in the middle of a query.
2. Scalar variables can only hold one value.
3. Scalar variables in SQL Server always begin with `@`. Cursor variables can be plain identifiers but you definitely don't want a cursor, here.
4. A simple `JOIN` will do what you're looking for. The subquery method works but is awkward (sticking queries in the `SELECT` statement), can't pull more than one column value, and can't be reused throughout the query like a `JOIN` can.
5. You can use a `CASE` statement directly on a column. There is no need to try to put the value into a variable first. And that wouldn't work anyway (see #2).
6. You can use the `IsNull` or `Coalesce` functions to turn a `NULL` into a `0` with simpler syntax.
7. I encourage you to use aliases that hint at the tables instead of using `A` and `B`. For example, `S` for `Students` and `O` for `OverwrittenScores`.

Taking all those points into consideration, you can do something like this instead:

```
SELECT
   S.StudentId,
   OverwrittenScore = Coalesce(O.OverwrittenScore, 0)
FROM
   dbo.Students S
   LEFT JOIN dbo.OverwrittenScores O
      ON S.StudentId = O.StudentID
      AND O.AssignmentId = @assignmentId
   LEFT JOIN dbo.SomeOtherTable T -- add another join here if you like
      ON S.StudentID = T.StudentID
      AND O.OverwrittenScore IS NULL
```

**UPDATE**

I added another `LEFT JOIN` for you above. Do you see how it joins on the condition that `O.OverwrittenScore IS NULL`? This seems to me like it will probably do what you want.

Again, if you will provide more detail I will show you more answer.

Also, for what it's worth, your edit to your post is overcomplicated. If you were going to write your query that way, it would be better like this:

```
SELECT
   S.StudentId,
   FinalScore = 
      Coalesce(
         (SELECT O.OverwrittenScore
         FROM dbo.OverwrittenScores O
         WHERE
            S.StudentId = O.StudentId
            AND O.AssignmentId = @assignmentId
         ), 
         (SELECT SomethingElse FROM SomewhereElse),
         0
      )
FROM dbo.Students S
```

I also encourage you when writing correlations or joins to put the *other* or *outer* table first in the join (as in `S.StudentId = O.StudentId` instead of `O.StudentId = S.StudentId`). I suggest this because it helps you understand the join faster, since you already know the local table and want to know the outer table, and thus your eye doesn't have to scan as far. I also recommend putting multiple conditions on separate lines. I promise you that you will be able to understand your own queries faster in the future if you get in the habit of doing this.

Comment: thanks for your response ErikE, can you see my update code? In it I've have a case where evaluates its value. The first two queries are equals, if this one is NULL then gets another value from another query

Comment: I updated as much as I could. Please provide MORE details if you want more help. Seriously. MORE DETAIL! You're asking for conceptual help but aren't providing enough concepts for me to really be able to help you!

Comment: thanke you so much, I really feel complicated to express my ideas in another language. I used your first code and is really what I need! I didn't have idea about what can do LEFT JOIN